# how to merge some columns from different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to merge the information from my two dataframes ("members" and "shipments") and therefore have for each row of members, the shipment information but I would like to keep only the "month" column. With the code below, I have what I want but I have all the shipping columns and not only the "month" column.

Code :

```
import pandas as pd 

members = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/members.csv")
expeditions = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-09-22/expeditions.csv")
df_members_expeditions = pd.merge(members,expeditions, on='expedition_id', how='inner')
df_members_expeditions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by merging the first dataframe with just the subset of the second dataframe that contains your two columns (the one to join on and the new one you want).

```py
df_members_expeditions = pd.merge(members,expeditions[['expedition_id','month']], on='expedition_id', how='inner')
```